# Accessing external url of vega data sets

Tags: angular, vega-lite, vega, vegas-viz, vega-embed

I have embedded `Vega` and `Vega-Lite` into my Angular application, and I can display them directly on my own `html` pages.

Some of the examples I am adopting contain links to external data files, which I have downloaded and installed in my app with `npm i vega-datasets` as instructed on [this](https://github.com/vega/vega-datasets) page.

Here is an example of an arc diagram that uses the `miserables.json` file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
    "description": "An arc diagram depicting character co-occurrence in the novel Les Misérables.",
    "width": 770,
    "padding": 5,
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "edges",
            "url": "../node_modules/vega-datasets/data/miserables.json",
            "format": {
                "type": "json",
                "property": "links"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "sourceDegree",
            "source": "edges",
            "transform": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregate",
                    "groupby": [
                        "source"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "targetDegree",
            "source": "edges",
            "transform": [
                {
                    "type": "aggregate",
                    "groupby": [
                        "target"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "nodes",
            "url": "../node_modules/vega-datasets/data/miserables.json",
            "format": {
                "type": "json",
                "property": "nodes"
            },
            "transform": [
                {
                    "type": "window",
                    "ops": [
                        "rank"
                    ],
                    "as": [
                        "order"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "lookup",
                    "from": "sourceDegree",
                    "key": "source",
                    "fields": [
                        "index"
                    ],
                    "as": [
                        "sourceDegree"
                    ],
                    "default": {
                        "count": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "lookup",
                    "from": "targetDegree",
                    "key": "target",
                    "fields": [
                        "index"
                    ],
                    "as": [
                        "targetDegree"
                    ],
                    "default": {
                        "count": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "formula",
                    "as": "degree",
                    "expr": "datum.sourceDegree.count + datum.targetDegree.count"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "scales": [
        {
            "name": "position",
            "type": "band",
            "domain": {
                "data": "nodes",
                "field": "order",
                "sort": true
            },
            "range": "width"
        },
        {
            "name": "color",
            "type": "ordinal",
            "range": "category",
            "domain": {
                "data": "nodes",
                "field": "group"
            }
        }
    ],
    "marks": [
        {
            "type": "symbol",
            "name": "layout",
            "interactive": false,
            "from": {
                "data": "nodes"
            },
            "encode": {
                "enter": {
                    "opacity": {
                        "value": 0
                    }
                },
                "update": {
                    "x": {
                        "scale": "position",
                        "field": "order"
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "field": "degree",
                        "mult": 5,
                        "offset": 10
                    },
                    "fill": {
                        "scale": "color",
                        "field": "group"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "from": {
                "data": "edges"
            },
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "stroke": {
                        "value": "#000"
                    },
                    "strokeOpacity": {
                        "value": 0.2
                    },
                    "strokeWidth": {
                        "field": "value"
                    }
                }
            },
            "transform": [
                {
                    "type": "lookup",
                    "from": "layout",
                    "key": "datum.index",
                    "fields": [
                        "datum.source",
                        "datum.target"
                    ],
                    "as": [
                        "sourceNode",
                        "targetNode"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "linkpath",
                    "sourceX": {
                        "expr": "min(datum.sourceNode.x, datum.targetNode.x)"
                    },
                    "targetX": {
                        "expr": "max(datum.sourceNode.x, datum.targetNode.x)"
                    },
                    "sourceY": {
                        "expr": "0"
                    },
                    "targetY": {
                        "expr": "0"
                    },
                    "shape": "arc"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "symbol",
            "from": {
                "data": "layout"
            },
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "x": {
                        "field": "x"
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "field": "y"
                    },
                    "fill": {
                        "field": "fill"
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "field": "size"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "from": {
                "data": "nodes"
            },
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "x": {
                        "scale": "position",
                        "field": "order"
                    },
                    "y": {
                        "value": 7
                    },
                    "fontSize": {
                        "value": 9
                    },
                    "align": {
                        "value": "right"
                    },
                    "baseline": {
                        "value": "middle"
                    },
                    "angle": {
                        "value": -90
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "field": "name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The 2 instances of `"url": "../node_modules/vega-datasets/data/miserables.json"` actually used to be `"url": "data/miserables.json"` in the online Vega Editor, but since I have copied the content into a file and placed it in my Angular app's `assets` folder, I modified the path accordingly.

Or at least I think it was done accordingly!

The graphs do not show, so I suspect I am doing the path adjustment wrong.

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong that the graphs do not show?

Here is a screenshot of my Angular project hierarchy:

[image]

The datasets are installed in a folder in `node_modules/vega-datasets/data/` and my

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read on the vega slack channel that it is (usually) bad practice to serve files from node modules, so make sure to copy them into (for example) your `assets` folder.

If you do that and copy that `json` file into your local `assets` directory, then all you need to do is replace your two `url`s with the following:

```
"url": "/assets/miserables.json"
```